# How to filter duplicates from a list of sets in python?

Tags: python

So I am working on a little project and I got stuck with a piece of code.
The code should filter all of the duplicate numbers in the list.
This is my code:

```
lijst = [{1,2,3,4,4}, {4,5}]
def unique(lijst):
    final_list = []
    for nummer in lijst:
        if nummer not in final_list:
            final_list.append(nummer)
    return final_list
print(unique(lijst))
```

When I print this I get this:

[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 5}]

But I want to get this:
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
The program should also work if the list changes.
I have no clue how to fix this.
Can anyone help?
It would be nice if you explained how you did it and why, because I am a python beginner, so than I can learn from this.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: note that `{1,2,3,4,4}` is actually `{1,2,3,4}`. Duplicates are already filtered out

Comment: Your `lijst` is a list with 2 elements, each of them is a set. This why you get 2 elements in your `final_list`. Are you sure this is the right input?

Comment: you probably don't get `[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 5}]` but rather `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5]]`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - No, the code above loops over a list that contains 2 elements, each is a set, and it append the sets to the final_list. So you get again a list of 2 sets (the first set is printed as {1, 2, 3, 4} because duplicates are removed even if they appear in the literal definition.

Answer (score 1):

```
lijst = [{1,2,3,4,4}, {4,5}]

x = set()
for seq in lijst:
    x |= set(seq)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate over the iterable and use `set` on the last result,

```
>>> x = [{1,2,3,4,4}, {4,5}]
>>> {z for y in x for z in y}
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Where should I apply this in my code?

Comment: golfing with set comprehension: `{z for y in x for z in y}`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre or that :)

Comment: @JosseLardinois you can put this instead as the body of the your `unique` function :)

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [[1,2,3,4,4], [4,5]]

a=[]
for each in l:
    for every in each:
        a.append(every)
l=a
print(set(a))
```

**OUTPUT**

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

Answer (score 0):

```
jst = [{1,2,3,4,4}, {4,5}]
def unique(lijst):
    A=set()
    for i in lijst:
            A=A.union(i)
    return(A)
print list(unique (jst))


[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

use set.difference in that case to get only {1,2,3}

Answer (score 0):

My method:

```
lijst = [{1,2,3,4,4},{4,5}]
result = []
sub1 = tuple(lijst[0])
sub2 = tuple(lijst[1])
for i in range(len(sub1)):
    result.append(sub1[i])
for i in range(len(sub2)):
    if sub2[i] not in result:
        result.append(sub2[i])
result = list(result)
print(result)
```

and my result is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
hope this useful.